# Overriding __eq__ and __hash__ without downgrading performace

Tags: python, performance, hash, overriding, equality

I have two classes Structure and Fragment that represent chemical structures.
If I compare two instances of the same class, the comparison should behave normally, but if I compare a structure with a fragment the comparison should be based on a string attribute that uniquely identify the chemical structure.

Unfortunately, in my attempt the run time increases dramatically (operations with sets and dictionaries).

class Structure:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Structure):
        return self is other
    else:
        return self.cansmiles is other.cansmiles_unstarred

def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.cansmiles)
```

Fragment **eq** and **hash** are implemented with the same logic.

The "cansmiles" string can be pretty long (usually 25, up to 100), I tried to slice it without luck.

Questions are: what is so magic in built in **hash** and **eq** to be so efficient? Is there a way to override them efficiently? Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Can I avoid computing the hash value every time `__hash__` is called?

Comment: Why are you using `is` instead of `==` for testing equality? The `is` operator checks for *identity*, i.e. if two variables point to the *very same* object. Use `==` and see if your performance issue goes away.

Comment: `object.__eq__` is efficient because it has no basis for comparing two objects *other* than simply checking if they are the same object or not. That is, `__eq__ = lambda x, y: x is y`.

Comment: @amain I think it's the opposite: `is` is faster than `==` because it checks ONLY a pointer. Anyway, for object or immutable types (like strings), equality eventually executes identity. In a simple test, equality takes twice the time.
python -m timeit "'a' is 'a'"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0415 usec per loop
python -m timeit "'a' == 'a'"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0835 usec per loop

Comment: @chepner that is exactly what I'm doing: testing for identity. There is only one extra `if` in my code, and i find suprising that it runs in 10x the time. I somehow feel that is the hash part the issue: when I ctrl+C, the execution is always inside the hash. That leads me to another question: how can I avoid to compute the hash each time `__hash__` is called?

Comment: You are doing an extra, unnecessary test of `other`'s type before, though. You probably still want `self.cansmiles == other.cansmiles`. As for the timing, `object.__eq__` is built-in to the interpreter; your `__eq__` function is defined in Python code.

Comment: @chepner sorry, there was an imprecision. When comparing same type, I could compare "cansmiles" (identity is faster tho), but when comparing different types, I must compare `Structure.cansmiles == Fragment.cansmiles_unstarred`.
What you say about timing is correct, and probably it's impossible to override it without loosing. Still the run time shift from 300s to 1500s... there should be something else.

Comment: @Thomas: "Anyway, for object or immutable types (like strings), equality eventually executes identity." is false. Try eg. `a = 'not always identical!'; b = 'not always identical' + '!'; a == b; a is b`. You should never use `is`, unless you *want* to test identity and not equality, or you're testing against a singleton, eg. `None`. Some people also like to abuse `is` for integers - that ends poorly, too: `257 is 256+1`. CPython caches small strings and integers, which is why `is` will often give the result you're expecting when testing. It also reuses the same object if you write the same ->

Comment: constant directly multiple times within the same code object (eg. inside a [eg. list] comprehension, directly inside the same function, or in the module scope). That's why `257 is 256+1` doesn't work: you aren't writing the same exact constant. But like I said, this isn't limited to that, you can get the same result even when writing the same constant, if it isn't in the same code object, eg. `[257 for x in (1,)][0] is [257 for y in (1,)][0]`. And even with small strings/integers, your code will break in other Python implementations, or if the limits change. ...So don't abuse `is`.

Comment: @Thomas I actually didn't claim any performance impacts when I asked you about the reason to use `is` for checking equality. @Aleksi Torhamo got straight to the point, I can only second his comment. The performance impact *could* be a side effect of using `is`, though, especially in set and dict hash table lookups. Did you actually *try* to use `==`?

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo I agree, the check for identity between strings is an abuse: I was trying to gain performance after I've read here on StackOverflow that "equality eventually executes identity". Between objects, instead, identity is exactly what i want to check.

Comment: @amain of course I did: they perform the same. If you read again your 1st comment you will see why I understood you were claiming `==` to be faster than `is`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, you have a bigger problem: Your code has bugs. While `is` might be slightly faster, it also does the wrong thing.

While some quick tests might lead you to believe it works - due to Python optimizing some simple cases - these examples show that it doesn't work in general:

```
def f():
    return 'not always identical!'

a = 'not always identical!'
b = f()

# Will print: True False -- that is, the strings are equal, but not the same string object
print(a == b, a is b)

x = 'a'
a = x*2
b = 'aa'

# Will print: True False -- that is, the strings are equal, but not the same string object
print(a == b, a is b)
```

As for your `__eq__()` implementation, it'll break if you try to compare anything other than `Structure`s and `Fragment`s (since other objects will probably not have `cansmiles`/`cansmiles_unstarred` attributes, giving an `AttributeError` - or if they do, the code will do the wrong thing, since you probably don't want to compare equal to an random unknown object).

Now, think about this part of your code:

```
if isinstance(other, Structure):
    return self is other
```

Since `self` is a `Structure`, if `self` is the same object as `other`, other is obviously a `Structure`, too - so the `if` is *kind of* unnecessary. If you look at both of these problems, you'll realize the whole thing is just the wrong way around: You don't need to check the type for the `is`, but you do need to check the type for the string check! Thus:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Fragment):
        return self.cansmiles == other.cansmiles_unstarred
    else:
        return self is other
```

Now, as for how this change will affect the speed of your dictionary lookups: It won't. Python optimizes dictionary lookups by first checking with `is`, before falling back to `==`. So if you do a lookup with the same type as you used to save the data, since your equality inside the same type is based on identity, the only time `__eq__()` will actually get called is if you have a hash collision (rare).

If you do a lookup with the other type though, the object won't be the same, so it'll fall back to `==` and call the `__eq__()` - but the change from `is` to `==` still won't affect the speed: `==` might be slightly slower than `is`, but function calls are an order of magnitude slower, so the time taken by `isinstance()` will dwarf the time taken by either comparison.

So why *are* the built-in `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` so much faster? Well, why is `sum(l)` faster than `for v in l: t += v`? Because running Python bytecode is way slower than running native code. In the comments, you said that `is` only checks a pointer - but that isn't really true, is it? You have to fetch the next opcode and its argument from the bytecode, select the correct handler, jump to the handler and so on.

If you say `def __eq__(self, other): return self is other`, and call that function, instead of doing "just a pointer comparison", you have to set up an execution frame, populate a dictionary for the local scope, do two lookups to the dictionary to get the values based on the names, push them in the stack, pop the values from the stack, do the comparison, push the result on the stack, pop the result from the stack, and finally return the value - and each step includes fetching and decoding the bytecode, jumping around, and so on. So yeah, that's going to be slower than the built-in `__eq__()` which is probably actually very close to "just a pointer comparison".

As for avoiding recalculating the hash: You already do - you're hashing strings, and strings cache their hashes, so they aren't being recalculated. The built-in `__hash__()` is based on the object's id, so it should be constant-time, so it'll obviously be faster than calculating the hash of a string, which should be linear-time. But even if the string hash was being recalculated, that's being done in native code, so the speed difference would be tiny - and dwarfed by the fact that you're switching from native code to running python bytecode when you define a custom one.

You can of course cache the value returned by `hash()` yourself - you'll need to add an if to check if the hash has already been calculated, but since calling functions is relatively slow, even with the added code the result will probably still be *slightly* faster. But you'd be adding code, and reducing the readability, for very small gains in speed. If you want speed, why don't you just simply use the strings as keys directly? Or if speed is really important, you might want to take a look at PyPy (or even Numba).